# Update ui from props in react js. Props to state handoff in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I am having trouble figuring out how to update my UI when my props are changed in a reactjs and redux build. This seems like a relatively normal and simple issue but I am struggling with it. I have found that the documentation from react surrounding this is woefully inadequate https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops (one paragraph with a brief explanation and no examples). I would also like to see this in the new and correct es6 format. 
As I understand it I can set my props and tie them so they update my state. I set initial props so the requested props are never null. I did same for state and none of it appears in render or in my state tree.

I have found this for setting my initial state and used it

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { userBirthdate: '1/2/1982', };
  }
}
```

I found this for updating the ui using the componentWillReceiveProps()

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.setState({
    userBirthdate: nextProps.userBirthdate
  });
}
```

But when I look through the react inspector there is no state for my container (showing a message of "Empty object" in the inspector under state). The props are updating and reflect my user selection in redux. As in when I select a new element it is reflected in redux fills the right props I am using but they do not get passed to state.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the lifecycle function `shouldComponentUpdate` will be the way to go for you

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { userBirthdate: '1/2/1982', };
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    if(this.props.userBirthdate !== nextProps.userBithdate) {
       return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the needed data is coming in through props, don't worry about "syncing" it to state unless you need to manipulate it within the component.

Instead, just use the props directly, for example:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component{

  static defaultProps = {
    userBirthdate: '1/2/1982'
  };

  render() {
    const { userBirthdate } = this.props;
    return <span>DOB: {userBirthdate}</span>;
  }
}
```